# LINUX LISH.H list_for_each infinite loop

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linked-list, infinite-loop

I'm trying to implement  a list of task_struct  and use it as a FIFO. In addition I need a function to go through the list and search for a particular task.

My problem is that the list_for_each macro gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Here below there is a snippet from my code:

```
typedef struct task_list_node {
   struct list_head next;
   struct task_struct *task;
} task_list_node;

task_list_node * find(struct semaphore *sem) 
{
   struct list_head * next;
   struct list_head task_list = sem->task_list;

   list_for_each(next, &task_list) {
      task_list_node * elem;
      // Get a pointer to the element on the list
      elem = list_entry(next, task_list_node, next);

      // [...]

   }
   return(NULL);   
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: try using `list_for_each_safe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_for_each()` itself is fine.

```
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

The problem is: `struct list_head task_list = sem->task_list;`

You are creating a structure like:

```
    |--------------------------------------------------------
   \/                                                        |
  head #a "sem->task_list"  ---element 1 .... element #N -----
                                   ^
  head #b "task_list" -------------|
```

`list_for_each()` should stop when `"pos" == head #a`, but you are not using `head #a "sem->task_list"` for iteration, but `head #b "task_list"`, so the stop condition is `"pos" == "task_list"` is not reached.

Should fix like:

```
list_for_each(next, &sem->task_list) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already solved it, I implemented it starting from another example. However your solution sounds good, I will try it.